# lein jack-in and lein swank don't work after upgrading leiningen to version 1.7.0

Tags: clojure, leiningen, swank-clojure

I've upgraded my leiningen version (previously I was using the 1.4). My slime version is the latest too. Now when I type `lein jack-in <port>` or `lein swank` I get this:

```
lein jack-in 9090
;;; Bootstrapping bundled version of SLIME; please wait...


(when (not (featurep 'slime-cdf283b4))
               (if (file-readable-p "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-cdf283b4.elc")
                 (load-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-cdf283b4.elc")
               (byte-compile-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-cdf283b4.el" t)))
(when (not (featurep 'slime-frame-colors-a24dd450))
               (if (file-readable-p "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-frame-colors-a24dd450.elc")
                 (load-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-frame-colors-a24dd450.elc")
               (byte-compile-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-frame-colors-a24dd450.el" t)))
(when (not (featurep 'slime-repl-79b38c83))
               (if (file-readable-p "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-repl-79b38c83.elc")
                 (load-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-repl-79b38c83.elc")
               (byte-compile-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-repl-79b38c83.el" t)))
(when (not (featurep 'slime-eldoc-d8b3cf74))
               (if (file-readable-p "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-eldoc-d8b3cf74.elc")
                 (load-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-eldoc-d8b3cf74.elc")
               (byte-compile-file "C:\Documents and Settings\Carlos/.emacs.d/swank/slime-eldoc-d8b3cf74.el" t)))
(sleep-for 0.1)
(run-hooks 'slime-load-hook) ; on port 9090
Warning: *log-events* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *log-events* or change the name.
Warning: *log-output* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *log-output* or change the name.
Warning: *namespace-re* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *namespace-re* or change the name.
    Warning: *current-connection* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *current-connection* or change the name.
    Warning: *default-encoding* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *default-encoding* or change the name.
    Warning: *pre-reply-hook* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *pre-reply-hook* or change the name.
Warning: *pre-reply-hook* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *pre-reply-hook* or change the name.
Warning: *thread-map-next-id* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *thread-map-next-id* or change the name.
Warning: *thread-map-next-id* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *thread-map-next-id* or change the name.
Warning: *thread-map* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *thread-map* or change the name.
Warning: *thread-map* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *thread-map* or change the name.
Warning: *mailboxes* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *mailboxes*
or change the name.
Warning: *mailboxes* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *mailboxes*
or change the name.
Warning: *protocol-version* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *protocol-version* or change the name.
Warning: *protocol-version* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *protocol-version* or change the name.
Warning: *current-package* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *current-package* or change the name.
Warning: *pending-continuations* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic
*pending-continuations* or change the name.
Warning: *sldb-stepping-p* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *sldb-stepping-p* or change the name.
Warning: *sldb-initial-frames* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically
rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *sldb-initial-frames* or change the name.
Warning: *sldb-level* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *sldb-level* or change the name.
Warning: *sldb-restarts* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *sldb-restarts* or change the name.
Warning: *debug-swank-clojure* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically
rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *debug-swank-clojure* or change the name.
Warning: *active-threads* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *active-threads* or change the name.
Warning: *active-threads* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *active-threads* or change the name.
Warning: *debug-quit-exception* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *debug-quit-exception* or change the name.
Warning: *debug-quit-exception* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *debug-quit-exception* or change the name.
Warning: *debug-continue-exception* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *debug-continue-exception* or change the name.
Warning: *debug-continue-exception* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *debug-continue-exception* or change the name.
Warning: *debug-abort-exception* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic
*debug-abort-exception* or change the name.
Warning: *debug-abort-exception* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic
*debug-abort-exception* or change the name.
Warning: *current-exception* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *current-exception* or change the name.
Warning: *current-env* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *current-env* or change the name.
Warning: *connections* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *connections* or change the name.
Warning: *connections* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *connections* or change the name.
Warning: *compiler-exception-location-re* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *compiler-exception-location-re* or change the name.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: print-doc in this context, compiling:(swank/commands/basic.clj:180)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6235)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3452)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6411)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$TryExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:2091)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5873)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6397)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6397)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5873)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6397)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6397)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5008)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3629)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6407)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6397)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:37)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:492)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6469)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5275)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at swank.swank$eval35$loading__4505__auto____36.invoke(swank.clj:11)
        at swank.swank$eval35.invoke(swank.clj:11)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at user$eval27.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: print-doc in this context
        at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6720)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6664)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6198)
        ... 93 more
```

OK, this error is really ugly but take a look at:

```
Bootstrapping bundled version of SLIME; please wait...
```

and

```
Warning: *current-env* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *current-env* or change the name.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Can you tell us what version of `swank-clojure` plugin you have installed? Also, could you please include your `project.clj` file in your port.

Comment: Hi..I'm using the latest swank-cloj (swank-clojure 1.4.0)...my project.clj is the default...I was thinking maybe could be an error in a downloaded package so I decided try with a default project (lein new testproject.. cd testproject.. lein swank) neither work :(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're running Clojure 1.3.0 with an old version of `swank-clojure` that's not compatible with 1.3.0.

The error in your post is this line:

```
Unable to resolve symbol: print-doc in this context, 
  compiling:(swank/commands/basic.clj:180)
```

`print-doc` was moved to `clojure.repl` in version 1.3.0 of Clojure.

What version of the `swank-clojure` plugin do you have installed?

Try installing the 1.4.0 version of the `swank-clojure` plugin with

```
lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.4.0
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer...well I've tried download again swank-clojure 1.4.0..it was downloaded and installed but th error still displayed..now..you're right..when I use the clojure 1.2.1 this work...I think than maybe I'm going use the clojure 1.2 version for a while with my windows OS...in linux everything works fine...thanks so much...anyway I will try resolve it and found answers...

Comment: Try creating a new project with `lein new test` and run `lein swank` there. Does that work? Maybe you have an old version of `swank-clojure` lying around somewhere.

Comment: I had issues with the lein install plugin not getting rid of previous jars in the plugin folder, and when lein runs it includes all the jar files present, and older versions listed first. so check the $HOME/.lein//plugins for old jars